# Cannot install atom packages on windows

Tags: node.js, github, atom-editor, node-gyp

I'm using **atom** with Windows 10 64bit. Here's the `apm -v`:

```
apm  1.0.5
npm  2.13.3
node 0.10.40
python 2.7.10
git 2.6.1.windows.1
visual studio
```

When trying to install packages for atom, say **atom-alignment**, it fails with no error message:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.40 | win32 | ia32
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp
```

With `apm install atom-alienment --verbose` it says:

```
Installing atom-alignment to C:\Users\Clive\.atom\packages REQUEST { url: 'https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment',
  json: true,
  retries: 4,
  proxy: null,
  strictSSL: true,
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'npm/2.13.3 node/v0.10.40 win32 ia32' },
  callback: [Function],
  method: 'GET' }
REQUEST make request https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment
REQUEST onRequestResponse https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment 200 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:29 GMT',
  status: '200 OK',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  etag: 'W/"03523dffe3f53177968c1303a52df1ff"',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
  'x-request-id': '31653053-aa0d-4c72-854b-4664ea3f8f85',
  'x-runtime': '0.056144',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
REQUEST finish init function https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment
REQUEST response end https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment 200 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:29 GMT',
  status: '200 OK',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  etag: 'W/"03523dffe3f53177968c1303a52df1ff"',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
  'x-request-id': '31653053-aa0d-4c72-854b-4664ea3f8f85',
  'x-runtime': '0.056144',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
REQUEST end event https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment
REQUEST has body https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment 7901
REQUEST emitting complete https://atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment
REQUEST { url: 'https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment/versions/0.12.1/tarball',
  proxy: null,
  strictSSL: true,
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'npm/2.13.3 node/v0.10.40 win32 ia32' },
  method: 'GET',
  callback: undefined }
REQUEST make request https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment/versions/0.12.1/tarball
REQUEST onRequestResponse https://www.atom.io/api/packages/atom-alignment/versions/0.12.1/tarball 302 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:31 GMT',
  status: '302 Found',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  location: 'https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'x-request-id': '86dabcce-559a-48f4-86a4-8c4dfe44b5cc',
  'x-runtime': '0.249618',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
REQUEST redirect https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1
REQUEST redirect to https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1
REQUEST {}
REQUEST make request https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1
REQUEST response end https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1 302 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:31 GMT',
  status: '302 Found',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  location: 'https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'x-request-id': '86dabcce-559a-48f4-86a4-8c4dfe44b5cc',
  'x-runtime': '0.249618',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
REQUEST onRequestResponse https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1 200 { 'content-length': '5677',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://render.githubusercontent.com',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'deny',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
  vary: 'Authorization,Accept-Encoding',
  etag: '"a32723dc258a5ef20b016f7570af69ea54d1a6d4"',
  'content-type': 'application/x-gzip',
  'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=Freyskeyd-atom-alignment-v0.12.1-0-ga32723d.tar.gz',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:38 GMT' }
REQUEST finish init function https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1
REQUEST response end https://codeload.github.com/Freyskeyd/atom-alignment/legacy.tar.gz/v0.12.1 200 { 'content-length': '5677',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://render.githubusercontent.com',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'deny',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
  vary: 'Authorization,Accept-Encoding',
  etag: '"a32723dc258a5ef20b016f7570af69ea54d1a6d4"',
  'content-type': 'application/x-gzip',
  'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=Freyskeyd-atom-alignment-v0.12.1-0-ga32723d.tar.gz',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:38 GMT' }
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Users\\Clive\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.0.19\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Clive\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.0.19\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'install',
gyp verb cli   '--target=0.30.7',
gyp verb cli   '--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell',
gyp verb cli   '--arch=ia32',
gyp verb cli   '--ensure',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.40 | win32 | ia32
gyp verb command install []
gyp verb install input version string "0.30.7"
gyp verb install installing version: 0.30.7
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 0.30.7
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created C:\Users\Clive\.atom\.node-gyp\.node-gyp\0.30.7
gyp verb created nodedir C:\Users\Clive\.atom\.node-gyp\.node-gyp\0.30.7
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
REQUEST { uri: 'https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz',
  headers: { 'User-Agent': 'node-gyp v2.0.2 (node v0.10.40)' },
  callback: undefined }
REQUEST make request https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
REQUEST onRequestResponse https://atom.io/download/atom-shell/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz 302 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:40 GMT',
  status: '302 Found',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  location: 'http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'x-request-id': '600ba5d5-bd31-431a-8c7b-92727d19e358',
  'x-runtime': '0.036269',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
REQUEST redirect http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
REQUEST redirect to http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
REQUEST {}
REQUEST make request http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz
REQUEST response end http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz 302 { server: 'Cowboy',
  connection: 'close',
  date: 'Sat, 10 Oct 2015 02:33:40 GMT',
  status: '302 Found',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; font-src \'self\'; frame-src \'self\' https://www.youtube.com; img-src https://* \'self\' data:; media-src \'none\'; object-src \'self\'; script-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://platform.twitter.com; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\';',
  location: 'http://gh-contractor-zcbenz.s3.amazonaws.com/atom-shell/dist/v0.30.7/node-v0.30.7.tar.gz',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'x-request-id': '600ba5d5-bd31-431a-8c7b-92727d19e358',
  'x-runtime': '0.036269',
  'x-rack-cache': 'miss',
  via: '1.1 vegur' }
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same issue. Windows 10 machine.

> 1. Be logged in as admin
> 2. Disable firewall and antivirus for install
>      (Step 3 did  it for me)
> 3. Disable User Account Control setting in the registry, 
>      KEY:
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA
> 4. Change the value to 0
> 5. Reboot your machine
> 6. When running the installer right click run as admin (yes even with uac off)
>
>    > Once the icon populates on the desktop then it should also appear in the start up.